# .Net 8 Intentional Non-Closed HTML Tags

Tags: .net-core, razor

I was wondering if there is a way in a .Net 8 Web App, to indicate that an HTML Tag is intentionally being left without a closing tag.

If I have a Header.cshtml as a Partial with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Nothing</title></head>
<body>
```

Then it gives warnings about `html` and `body` not having closing tags in Visual Studio but it is intentional in order to be in a View like

```
@page
@await Html.PartialAsync("/Header.cshtml")
<p>Nothing</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I know this can be done with a Shared Layout but this only to illustrate the issue

Comment: You haven't told us why. What do you want to achieve by leaving those end tags?

Comment: Partials are meant to be included 'in the middle' of a page which has the necessary surrounding html.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing this but it feels a bit dirty to do. If I use `@**@` then I can indicate the Razor Interpreter must ignore the section

Updated Header.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@*<html lang="en">*@
<head><title>Nothing</title></head>
@*<body>*@
```

I'm going to leave it here for now but hoping that there is a better way